# PhysicsBody affected by change of anchorPoint

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a situation where i need to use the resizeToHeight method (to zero), but i want to achieve a sliding door effect, where the resize happens from the bottom and not the center of the image (with an anchorPoint of (0.5,0.5), the resize pretty much happens in the middle.

Now, if i change the anchorPoint to  (0,0), the resize occurs the way i want it, but the physicsbody of the object is not really affected by the change of the anchorPoint, thus messing with my collision detection (the invisible frame actually also collides and not the visible part of the image).

Based on what i could find online, it looks that maybe it's not the best idea to change the anchor point to CGPointZero. If that is the case, how can i handle this properly ? Or if CGPointZero is the way to go about it, how do i handle the physicsBody discrepancy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

disconnect the sprite from the physics body, ie have a node that represents the body and another that represents the door image, that way you can move, scale them independently.

Best solution is probably to use a SKNode with physics and add the SKSpriteNode as child so you can offset it in relation to the physics body in any way you like, without having to constantly synchronize their position/rotation.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds good, I will try that in a few. Looks like it will work just fine.